# Additive perturbation bounds on the eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

I am reading this paper:

http://society.math.ntu.edu.tw/~journal/tjm/V16N1/TJM-258.pdf

where the authors find additive perturbation bounds on the matrix of the eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix. I am not a mathematician, and I am struggling to understand their Theorem 2.1, where actually they propose this bound.

My understanding, is that it can be simplified as follows: 
Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be an Hermitian matrix, with eigendecomposition
$$
A = U \Lambda U^{'},\,\,\,\,\,\Lambda = diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)
$$
and
$$
\tilde{A} = A + \Delta_A,\,\,\,|| \Delta_A ||_F =\epsilon
$$
a perturbed, Hermitian matrix, with eigendecomposition
$$
\tilde{A} = \tilde{U} \tilde{\Lambda}  \tilde{U}^{'}
$$
Then, 
$$
||U - \tilde{U}||_F = \frac{\epsilon}{\min_{i\neq j}|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|} + O(\epsilon^2),\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\epsilon\to 0
$$

Does this make any sense?
There exist additive perturbation bounds on the eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix?

Comment: This should follow from the standard perturbation theory for the non-degenerate case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#First_order_corrections  (see especially the formula for $|n^{(1)}\rangle$ near the bottom of the section; the article is written in a physics style, but it's easy to make these things rigorous)